# Async operation freezing UI

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, datagrid, async-await

I'm working on a small application that displays a lists of people in a `DataGrid`. I've dipped my toe in the `async` thread-pool (punny, eh?) and most of it has worked well. However, I am now running into a problem. I understand the origins of the problem, but I'm stumped for a solution.

In my `DataGrid`, I have a `Style` with `DataTriggers` to update the `Visibility` of my rows based on a property of my view model. I use the property during a Levenshtein distance search to determine if the rows will be displayed. When I clear the search, I set the property `IsResult` to `true` on all objects in the collection to re-display the full list.

I am aware that the problem is the rapid `Layout` updates of the UI, rather than the iteration process itself. I have confirmed this with performance profiling. I know `async/await` isn't a magic solution to all UI issues, so I just need some direction on how to manage this operation more gracefully.

The project isn't large enough to warrant the complexity of running the `DataGrid` in `Virtual` mode, so I'm hoping there is another solution, whether in how I'm executing the search or how to corral `DataGrid`.

**DataGrid**

```
    <Style x:Key="EditableDataGrid" TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="AntiqueWhite"/>
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="GridDoubleClick"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Editing}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Adding}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <DataGrid Name="FlaggedPersonDataGrid"
              Grid.Column="0" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding FlaggedPeople}" 
              Style="{StaticResource EditableDataGrid}">

        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsResult}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Last Name" 
                                Binding="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="First Name" 
                                Binding="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                             Color="#FF3399FF"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

    </DataGrid>
```

**Search Function**

```
    private async Task ExecuteSearchAsync()
    {

        string searchTerm = SearchText.Text;
        double lastNameScore, firstNameScore, distanceScore, searchSensitivity;

        ObservableCollection<FlaggedPersonViewModel> searchBase = contextViewModel.FlaggedPeople;

        searchSensitivity = SensitivitySlider.Value / 100;

        await Task.Run
            (() =>
            {
                foreach (FlaggedPersonViewModel person in searchBase)
                {
                    lastNameScore = GetLevenshteinDistance(searchTerm, person.LastName, false);
                    lastNameScore = (person.LastName.Length - lastNameScore) / person.LastName.Length;

                    firstNameScore = GetLevenshteinDistance(searchTerm, person.FirstName, false);
                    firstNameScore = (person.FirstName.Length - firstNameScore) / person.FirstName.Length;

                    distanceScore = System.Math.Max(firstNameScore, lastNameScore);

                    if (distanceScore > searchSensitivity)
                        person.IsResult = true;
                    else
                        person.IsResult = false;
                }
            });
    }
```

**Clear Search Function**

```
    private async Task ClearSearchAsync()
    {
        ObservableCollection<FlaggedPersonViewModel> searchBase = contextViewModel.FlaggedPeople;

        await Task.Run
            (() =>
            {
                foreach (FlaggedPersonViewModel person in searchBase)
                    person.IsResult = true;
            });
    }
```

**Handler Calling Search Operations**

```
    private async void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (contextViewModel.Searching)
        {
            contextViewModel.Processing = true;

            //Already searching, revert to clear state
            contextViewModel.Searching = false;
            await ClearSearchAsync();

            contextViewModel.Processing = false;
        }
        else
        {
            contextViewModel.Processing = true;

            contextViewModel.Searching = true;
            await ExecuteSearchAsync();

            contextViewModel.Processing = false;
        }
    }
```

**Performance Profile**

[image: Performance Profile]

**EDIT**

I removed `await Task.Run` from the `ClearSearchAsync` function, to run the process on the main thread. It seems to have decreased performance further.

1.42s in the async run, 2.39 in the synchronous run

[image]

**Update 07/14/2017**
For the time being, I've just resorted to re-running the query and throwing a fresh collection into the grid. I'm not really satisfied with this, as it seems like using a sledgehammer for a detail job.

Comment: WPF is not thread-safe.  You must not modify UI-bound objects on other threads.

Comment: I'm modifying the underlying collection, which fires a `NotifyPropertChanged` event

Comment: Do all your UI updates at once in the UI thread. For instance, the `Task.Run` in `ClearSearchAsync` is completely useless and counter-productive: the only costly operation in it is `person.IsResult = true;`, which requires switching back to the UI thread

Comment: @KevinGosse Wouldn't that make the entire operation synchronous and lock the UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

Alot of moving parts especially on the UI tends to slow down updates when many action/events try to execute at the same time.

I see no immediate issues with the above code but advise refactoring some of the method calls to use explicit dependencies, especially given the async nature of the calls so as to identify how UI dependent components are being interacted with.

ExecuteSearchAsync Refactored

```
private async Task ExecuteSearchAsync(string searchTerm, ObservableCollection<FlaggedPersonViewModel> searchBase, double searchSensitivity) {
    double lastNameScore, firstNameScore, distanceScore;
    await Task.Run
    (() => {
        foreach (FlaggedPersonViewModel person in searchBase) {
            lastNameScore = GetLevenshteinDistance(searchTerm, person.LastName, false);
            lastNameScore = (person.LastName.Length - lastNameScore) / person.LastName.Length;

            firstNameScore = GetLevenshteinDistance(searchTerm, person.FirstName, false);
            firstNameScore = (person.FirstName.Length - firstNameScore) / person.FirstName.Length;

            distanceScore = System.Math.Max(firstNameScore, lastNameScore);

            if (distanceScore > searchSensitivity)
                person.IsResult = true;
            else
                person.IsResult = false;
        }
    });
}
```

ClearSearchAsync Refactored

```
private async Task ClearSearchAsync(ObservableCollection<FlaggedPersonViewModel> searchBase) {

    await Task.Run
        (() => {
            foreach (FlaggedPersonViewModel person in searchBase)
                person.IsResult = true;
        });
}
```

Event handler refactored.

```
private async void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (contextViewModel.Searching) {
        contextViewModel.Processing = true;

        //Already searching, revert to clear state
        contextViewModel.Searching = false;
        await ClearSearchAsync(contextViewModel.FlaggedPeople);

        contextViewModel.Processing = false;
    } else {
        contextViewModel.Processing = true;

        contextViewModel.Searching = true;
        await ExecuteSearchAsync(SearchText.Text, contextViewModel.FlaggedPeople, SensitivitySlider.Value / 100);

        contextViewModel.Processing = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the pointers on refactoring. I want to get base functionality and go back for a cleanup, so I'll come back and take a closer look at this.